# What is R class in android

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Understand the R class in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6804053/understand-the-r-class-in-android)

I cant understand why use 'R' Class in android application.

```
 setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

Can explain why use R used here.

Comment: There are n number of similar questions

Comment: As a noob android developer I started searching the same thing and wound up here. Very helpful question and tagging

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your question is duplicate of [Understand the R class in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6804053/understand-the-r-class-in-android)

> When your application is compiled, aapt generates the R class, which
>   contains resource IDs for all the resources in your res/ directory.
>   For each type of resource, there is an R subclass (for example,
>   R.drawable for all drawable resources) and for each resource of that
>   type, there is a static integer (for example, R.drawable.icon). This
>   integer is the resource ID that you can use to retrieve your resource.

I got this detail from the below link ,check this once for more details :
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html

Answer (score 3):

R.java which is Automatically System generated file it contains the id of each resources used in Application which is used to make refrence.

Answer (score 2):

R.class holds reference for all your android resources..  without which you cannot access any resources (drawable, layout, xmls etc) And R.class is Autogenerated.

Answer (score 2):

`R.class` contains **IDs** for all your **android resources**.

Answer (score 1):

R is the class that contains all the resource ids for your application.

Answer (score 1):

Its a resource class, contains ID for for all resources. Here you can also use

```
 setContentView(main);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find more info here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.html