# error: package R does not exist. Do I have to add the packages?

Tags: android, xml

I have added some java functions from Project A into Project B. Then, when I try to run Project B, I received the error. When I compare the xml file from both projects, they have different packages.

So do I need to add the packages from Project A into Project B as well ? If yes, how do I do that ?

Please help, I am very new to this

Code for Project B is as below

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="org.tensorflow.demo"
>
```

Code for Project A is as below

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.ocrreader"
android:installLocation="auto" >
```

These are the files that I added from Project A to Project B
[Files from Project A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q24pC.png),

[Added into Project B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhbOA.png)

[the new error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vhdC.png)

Comment: Show your methods that you added.

Comment: I simply copy java files from Project A into java files of Project B @Lekr0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [package R does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12986301/package-r-does-not-exist)

Comment: Can you post that files you copied from project A to B

Comment: Hi @Tedinoz, what do you mean by that ?

Comment: @Lekr0 I have edited the question, and attached images

Comment: @sarah.isml I mean that the error "_package R does not exist_" is covered in several StackOverflow posts and your question could have already been solved by the linked post. You might re-read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You are expected to have researched your question and "...and keep track of what you find. Even if you don't find a useful answer elsewhere on the site, including links to related questions that haven't helped can help others in understanding how your question is different from the rest."

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the most common errors you get when you copy-paste Java classes from one project to another.

What you need to do is: 
You need to copy those three classes right?
So, in Project B, make three new classes of the same name and each time copy paste the code of those three classes from Project A, just excluding the name of the package, which is in the first line of every class. 
Then compile the project B. Your errors should be resolved.

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion, I will try and update you soon. Also, do I need to copy the ‘import’ part from Project A as well ?

Comment: Yes, please copy everything except the package line on top of the class. See if it works :)

Comment: I have done it, but now I got error such as "cannot find symbol variable ocr_capture", "cannot find symbol variable preview" and "cannot find symbol variable graphicOverlay". is there anyway I can show you the image of the error

Comment: Yeah, just edit the question and include the image of the error.

Comment: Hey, saw the error. Check the layout file of this activity, OCR activity. You must have some different  named XML file for this activity. Just change the name in setContentView in the  java class according to the name you have in the XML Layout file for this activity.