# "error: package R does not exist" in all Direction classes after android studio update

Tags: android, android-studio, android-navigation-graph, android-safe-args

I Updated my Android studio to ChipMunk 2021.2.1 and then Android Studio recommend me to move package name from Android Manifest to build.gradle :

from:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="myPackageName">
    ...
```

to:

```
android {
    namespace 'myPackageName'
    ...
}
```

And after this change I get this kind of error in all generated Directions classes:

```
error: package R does not exist
@Override
public int getActionId() {
      return R.id.action_navigateToSomewhere;
```

I've [read this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12986301/package-r-does-not-exist) but it doesn't help me.

**Workaround:** The only way I found to solve the problem is to revert Android Studio recommended changes which seems ridiculous.

I guess it's a bug in navigation. Is there any other way to solve this problem?

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/216503249

Answer (score 0):

Connect your VPN then
Build/Rebuild project or Invalidate cache and restart

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't help

Comment: @MiladFaridnia Consider to your name i told that, because the most building problems for Iranians are the filtered domains and governments limitations. Anyway make sure about your internet connection and your VPN, Update your dependencies and also your Gradle version and some stuffs like these

Comment: Connection problems has been solved for years(at least for me)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I'm sure its not about connection

Comment: @MiladFaridnia `android.enableAapt2=true` add this to your **gradle.properties** and rebuild

Comment: Nope. It doesn't help :(
Anyway thanks for follow up.
you can add your answer I will up vote.

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine in **Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1**

You need to move package name from build.gradle app level to manifest as below -

Remove package name from build gradle

```
android  { 
    namespace 'com.appname' //remove this line
}
```

Add below line to manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="com.example.app"> //add package name to manifest
```