# How can i link these 10 digits numbers to there respective XML files?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am new in android development, I have made some basic apps.

```
setContentView(2130903071);  
a = (AgreeementView)findViewById(2131361889);
```

Now I am trying to study other android apps codes (know what I am saying). when I study these `java` classes I found these two lines(shown on top). what is these 10 digit numbers ,I know they are referring to `XML` files but how can i found those files.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are identifiers stored in R file. So whenever you create an identifier in XML (let's call it your_id) - you should address it like R.id.your_id. But it seems that you'd better read a little bit more of theory- Google has a really good set of guides

Comment: Can you be more specific please. I want to know that specific xml file  this 10 digit number referring to..  i dont have R file i have just decompile an android app to study it. And how can i regenerate R file. thanks for your help

Comment: R file is generated dynamically - have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6804095/1320299) for more details