# Android studio hides R class

Tags: android, android-studio

I was searching about R class in my project to get look on it without editing it.

When I press ctrl and click on R Android studio opens the resourse file instead of R class

Where does it exist in my project structure?

This is not about understanding R class in Android, It is about finding it the project for just having look inside it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understand the R class in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6804053/understand-the-r-class-in-android)

Comment: No I understand what is R , I want to know where is it in the project structure

Comment: @Ammar Atef it is auto generated class the solution is that to once clean your project and build it again, after clean every time it is automatically generated by android studios based on resources.

Comment: You should NEVER touch R.java...

Comment: from the possible duplicate: "is the dynamically generated class, created during build process"

Comment: But it still in the project structure and I want just to look at, answers helped me thanks all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find R class by searching it with "shift + cmd + o" or "double shift".

I guess new android studio update directs to the xml source of the resource.

Answer (score 2):

Please check in this path "app\build\intermediates\incremental-verifier\debug\your.package"