# Concept of R.java class

Tags: java, android

I just have few questions to solidify my understanding to R.java class.

(1): Does it generated at run-time or compile-time? 
To test it, I created a new 'Button' with a text, the 'id' of the 'Button' is 'actMain_btnTest' and the name attribute of its text in 'strings.xml' is
'btn_test'. Then in the java file I referred to the 'Button' using 'findViewById' and it was accessible. Therefore, I would say that the 'R.java' 
can be generated at compile time. But, then I navigated to 'R.java' to make sure that the 'actMain_btnTest' and 'btn_test' was added to 'R.java', but surprisingly, they were not existing!!
Now, anew question popped-up, how the 'id' was accessile while it was not yet added to 'R.java'?!

(2): What is the relation between 'R class' and 'Android Resource Manager'? how they work together?is it only for localization?!

(3): Since 'R class' contains sub-classes which contain 'ids' of the App's resources, and each 'id' is assigned to a value. For example,

```
public static final int request_identifiers=0x7f060019;
```

What does '0x7f060019' refer to? is it an address in the memory??!!

Comment: Helpful SO explanations and links at:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6804053/understand-the-r-class-in-android

Answer (score 0):

It is an auto-generated file by aapt (Android Asset Packaging Tool) that contains resource IDs for all the resources of res/ directory.

If you create any component in the activity_main.xml file, id for the corresponding component is automatically created in this file. This id can be used in the activity source file to perform any action on the component.